# Filetype() and is_dir() showing different result

Tags: php

I am looping through the folders to check their filesizes. I realized a folder is returning false to is_dir() { meaning it is not a directory }. I was surprised, since I know this is actually a directory, and I am using absolute path. I tried filetype instead, but then it tells me the same directory is actually an directory. Why does the two function show different results?

```
$filepath = ‘H:\800_その他★’;
$filepath = mb_convert_encoding($filepath, ‘SJIS’, ‘UTF-8’);
$isDir = is_dir($filepath) ? “dir” : “file”;
$filetype = filetype($filepath);
printf(“%s %s %s\n”, $filepath, $isDir, $filetype);
// Result : H:\800_その他★ dir dir

$filepath = ‘H:\830_SEIBI予算管理’;
$filepath = mb_convert_encoding($filepath, ‘SJIS’, ‘UTF-8’);
$isDir = is_dir($filepath) ? “dir” : “file”;
$filetype = filetype($filepath);
printf(“%s %s %s\n”, $filepath, $isDir, $filetype);
// Result : H:\830_SEIBI予算管理 file dir
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: That is the problem. I do not know how to reproduce this, since most of the directory works, but specific folder does not.

Comment: Show us your code first of all, so that we can make sure it is not due to a mistake you made. And then, give more details - what is the folder structure, which specific directory is affected, etc.

Comment: Added the source code. Both folder is a directory.

Comment: `mb_onvert_encoding()` -- obviously that's not code that is able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Modified the typo. I can not copy paste the source code due to network segregation. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, what do you mean with "network segregation"?

Comment: I am unable to access internet on my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

from the manual:

> Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a directory, FALSE
>   otherwise.

So check that the file exists with file_exists, a not existing file return false even it is not a directory

For better check change the line to:

```
$isDir = is_dir($filepath)===true ? “dir” : “file”;
```

maybe in some case the result could be not false but null or something else equivalent to false

Comment: Why on earth would anyone ever compare something that's guaranteed to be either `true` or `false` using `=== true`?